# Missing VuforiaEngine.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, vuforia

I have successfully built a Unity Vuforia app for Android, everything works as expected. Now, I am looking to build a Windows standalone version of the same app. My Windows standalone build cannot find the `VuforiaEngine.dll`. The location where it is looking for the file doesn't exist i.e. `MyApp_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/VuforiaEngine.dll`.

When I build and run the Windows app, I am presented with an error about a missing `VuforiaEngine.dll`.

I noticed in the Unity project package for Vuforia Engine AR, the plugins folder has sub-folders for `Windows/x64`. Inside here is a few plugins, most notably `VuforiaEngine.dll` (which my standalone build is struggling to locate). When inspecting this `VuforiaEngine.dll` plugin, I can see the supported platforms does not include standalone builds (it only includes Editor). I am unable to edit this plugin directly.

Steps to reproduce the behaviour:

- Download Vuforia Engine from Unity Asset Store
- Configure Vuforia Engine in your project
- Build a Windows standalone development build
- Run the build
- See the error in the on-screen console log

[windows standalone app error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfQgo.png)

I have upgraded my Vuforia version to the latest release (10.18) via the Unity Asset Store and also upgraded my Unity version to their latest release (2022.3.11f1). I also played with many settings, although I am still unable to run my Windows standalone build with Vuforia initialised.

I expected the Windows standalone version to run similar to the Android version, using a connected webcam instead of the mobile device camera.

---

Has anyone come across this? I found some old posts online from users encountering similar issues on Mac, but I haven't found anyone with this particular issue on a Windows machine.

Comment: was it in the plugins folder in your editor? did you copy all the files when you buitl it?

Comment: @BugFinder Nope, I don't have a Plugins folder in my editor. I know I can create one, although I tried this and copied in the VuforiaEngine.dll from the Unity packages. I then set this DLL to support standalone builds. When running a build with this plugin setup, I am presented with "Unable to initialise Vuforia".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuforia Engine does not support Win32 (or 64) as a native platform. You can run engine in Unity PlayMode but you cannot create a standalone Win32 app.

If you want to create an app to run on Windows you have to create a UWP application as explained here https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/getting-started-vuforia-engine-windows-10-development

Similarly, MacOS is not a supported deployment platform (beside Unity PlayMode) one can only build and deploy iOS applications.

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't realise standalone Win32 apps were a no-go with Vuforia. I'm setting my machine up for UWP development now. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble building the UWP project, but that's another issue. Thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot.